# Django inline and alternatives to list_display_links

Tags: django, django-admin

My model consist of a Person, Contract and Project classes. A contract is made when a Person has a project.

I also have an inline in order to show at the same time a person with his contract. As *list_display_links* doesn't work together with inlines I use a function to link the field *type_contract* with its Contract page but when I try to do the same with the field *project* it takes me to Contract as well (I guess because it's inside the class Contract and not Project).

So my question is: how to link the poject showed in the inline with its respective person/contract?

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Name"))
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Surname"))
    address = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Address"))

class Contract(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank = True, null = True) #related project
    type_contract = models.CharField(max_length = 9, blank = True, choices = TYPO_CONTRACTO, verbose_name = _(u"Type of contract(Full time/grant/Partial time...)"))

    def link_to_contract(self): #Allows me to link to the contract class
        if self.id:
            return "<a href='../../contract/%s' >%s</a>" % (str(self.id), str(self.type_contract))
    else:
        return "Not present"

    link_to_contract.allow_tags = True
    link_to_contract.short_description = "Type contract"

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Name"))
    principal_researcher = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank = True, verbose_name=_(u"Researcher associated with the project"))
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [
        ContractInline,
    ]

class ContractInline(admin.TabularInline):
    readonly_fields = ["project", "link_to_contract"]
    list_display = ["type_contract", "project"]

    fieldsets = [
        [ None,
            {
                "fields": [
                    ("link_to_contract"),#
                ]
            }
        ],
        [ None,
            {
                "fields": [
                    ("project"),
                ]
            }
        ],

    ]

    model = Contract
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Contract)
class ContractAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display_links = ["proyecto", "persona"]
list_display = ["type_contract, "person", "project"]

@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display_links = ["principal_researcher", "name"]
    list_display = ["name", "principal_researcher"]
```

Comment: Show the code of your modeladmin and inline, please.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on the above answer:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

fields = ('link_to_project', ..)

def link_to_project(self): 
    if self.project.id:
        return format_html("<a href='../../project/%s' >%s</a>" % (str(self.project.id), str(self.project.name))
    else:
        return "Not present"
link_to_project.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 def link_to_project(self): 
    if self.project.id:
        return "<a href='../../project/%s' >%s</a>" % (str(self.project.id), str(self.project.name))
 else:
    return "Not present"
```